# Spit out code formatting errors than actually formatiing in golang

Tags: go, gofmt

I am working on a large go codebase and go code doesn't seem to be properly formatted.

I want to know if there is an option in go that will in some way assert me that what places I need to change the code styling. I am not using any IDE. `go fmt` does that job but I do not want the styling to be taken care of automatically. I could not find any option / parameter that I could pass to `go fmt` to do the same.

Is there any way I can either (sort of) dry run go fmt and spit out the formatting mistakes or use any other utility to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `go fmt` command runs the [gofmt](https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/) command. Use the `gofmt` command directly for more control.

```
# use -d flag to print difference between file at path and formatted file
gofmt -d path

# no flags prints the formatted file to stdout.  This is the dry run.
gofmt path
```